# trouble with jQuery lifecycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

index.html:

```
<input type="text" id="inputs" name="inputs">
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="submit">
```

script.js:

```
(function() {
    function myFunction(input) {
        alert(input);
    }
    $('#btnAdd').click(myFunction($('#inputs').val()));
});
```

I'm having trouble getting my javascript to run when my button is clicked. I assume I am misusing the ready function or my page has yet to register the button, but I am unable to break at any linein the javascript when I debug the page. Can someone tell me the proper way to get this to function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way it's written, the code you provide for script.js would never run. You probably want to put your function into a call to jQuery so it gets executed when the DOM is loaded.

Also, you need to wrap your click callback inside an anonymous function, or else it will execute myFunction when you're trying to add the callback instead of on the actual click.

```
$(function() {
    function myFunction(input) {
        alert(input);
    }
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        myFunction($('#inputs').val())
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9du8rxw0/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add callback to your click event and for `$(document).ready(function(){  })` the short hand is `$(function(){  })`.and it is better to write custom functions outside of document ready.

```js
    $(function() {
      
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            myFunction($('#inputs').val())
        });
    });

  function myFunction(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputs" name="inputs">
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that about custom functions being outside of the document ready.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a $ before your self-invoking function will tell jQuery to wait for the entire page, including your myFunction definition to load prior to execution.

like

```
$(function() {
    function myFunction(input) {
        alert(input);
    }
    $('#btnAdd').click(myFunction($('#inputs').val()));
});
```

then make sure either myFunction is declared in global scope, or better yet, wrap within your self-invoking function as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that the DOM is not yet loaded, and that your attempt to shorthand the call to `.ready()` is erroneous. Try prefixing with `$`:

Also, your event handler setup is not doing what you want.

```
// Need $ before your parens (shorthand for .ready())
$(function() {
    function myFunction(eventData) {
        alert(eventData.inputValue); // <-- get input value from eventData
    }

    // This is not proper usage of .click()
    // https://api.jquery.com/click/
    // $('#btnAdd').click(myFunction($('#inputs').val()));

    // You want to pass the relevant eventData as the first param,
    // and a reference to your handler in the second.
    $('#btnAdd').click( { inputValue: $('#inputs').val() }, myFunction);
});
```

Although, if you don't need `myFunction` to be defined separately, you might be better off with @Gerasimos' suggestion.

Comment: Please ignore the anonymous downvote. I have updated this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need the `$` in front of `(function()`, and your click function needs curly braces.

```js
$(function() {
    function myFunction(input) {
        alert(input);
    }
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){myFunction($('#inputs').val())});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputs" name="inputs">
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="submit">
```